# How to use jquery plugin flexslider in webpack 5 with react ssr

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I have created a sample project repo https://github.com/nikhilgoswami/webpack-5-react-with-jquery-plugin.git

I get error jQuery is not defined when importing the plugin flexslider

I tried expose-loader and provide-plugin but to no use

Answer (score 0):

Add the following configuration to your webpack.config.js file to ensure that jQuery is accessible globally and usable by your application:

```
   const webpack = require('webpack');
   module.exports = {
         // ...
    plugins: [
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     $: 'jquery',
     jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      }),
     ],
     // ...
   };
```

In your React component, import jQuery and Flexslider:

```
 import $ from 'jquery';
 import 'flexslider';

 class MyComponentClass extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
   // Initialize Flexslider
   $(this.slider).flexslider();
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <div ref={(slider) => { this.slider = slider; }}>
        // Slides go here
      </div>
     );
}
}
 export default MyComponentClass;
```

Make sure to include the required CSS and JavaScript files for Flexslider when rendering your React component on the server:

```
import MyComponent from './MyComponentClass';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

// Read the Flexslider's JavaScript and CSS files.
const flexsliderCss = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 
const flexsliderJs = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 
'../node_modules/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js'), 'utf8');

// Render the React component and include the CSS and JavaScript files for 
Flexslider
const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
<MyComponent />,
);

const finalHtml = `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
     <title>My Application</title>
     <style>${flexsliderCss}</style>
  </head>
 <body>
    <div id="app">${html}</div>
     <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
     <script>${flexsliderJs}</script>
   </body>
 </html>
 `;

res.send(finalHtml);
```

Comment: On React SSR import 'flexslider'; will throw error jQuery not defined

Comment: you can make this component run on the client side only. But jQuery runs on document and window objects and that object we cannot find those on the server.

Comment: @NisargThakkar Can you explain how to make component render only on client?

Answer (score 0):

First of you can install plugin using below command

```
npm install jquery flexslider --save
```

Then after create new file **jquery-global.js** in your src folder and put below code

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $;
```

Need to Webpack configuration file **webpack.config.js** add below code and configure as per your need

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
    }),
  ],  
};
```

Add below code in your **server.js** file

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
global.$ = global.jQuery = jquery;
```

Here is your updated code can you try this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'flexslider';

class FlexSlider extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    $(this.slider).flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      slideshowSpeed: 3000,
      controlNav: false,
      directionNav: true,
      prevText: "",
      nextText: ""
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="flexslider" ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)}>
        <ul className="slides">
          <li><img src="http://example.com/slide1.jpg" alt="Slide 1" /></li>
          <li><img src="http://example.com/slide2.jpg" alt="Slide 2" /></li>
          <li><img src="http://example.com/slide3.jpg" alt="Slide 3" /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FlexSlider;
```

I Hope it should be work

Comment: did you verify your answer by running project?

Comment: Not in running project but before i was tried with testing demo